Singleton SettingsManager with Swift 6 Strict Concurrency
I'm trying to migrate my (tiny) macOS and iOS app to Swift 6.
I have the following singleton SettingsManager class:
final class SettingsManager: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SettingsManager()
    private init() {}

    @AppStorage("showTimeLeft") var showTimeLeft = true
    @AppStorage("hideAppOnTimerStart") var hideAppOnTimerStart = false
    // More settings here
}

This class is used in different places throughout my app, as in the following pseudocode:
if SettingsManager.shared.showTimeLeft {
    Text("Time left here")
}


What is the proper way of migrating this class to Swift 6? I'm currently getting the following error:

Static property 'shared' is not concurrency-safe because non-'Sendable' type 'SettingsManager' may have shared mutable state

Xcode gives me three options:

Class 'SettingsManager' does not conform to the 'Sendable' protocol
Annotate 'shared' with '@MainActor' if property should only be accessed from the main actor
Disable concurrency-safety checks if accesses are protected by an external synchronization mechanism

The first option (making SettingsManager conform to Sendable) gives me a new error: "Stored property '_showTimeLeft' of 'Sendable'-conforming class 'SettingsManager' is mutable"
Annotating the entire class with @MainActor works in so far as it removes all errors, but is this consider good practice? I don't yet know much about Swift, but my belief is that @MainActor is primarily intended for UI code? I may be wrong about that, however.
The third option, I think, does not apply here.

P.S.: I don't really know what I'm doing, and it's entirely possible this singleton pattern is a terrible idea in general --- just let me know if that's the case.

Maybe don’t use a singleton at all and instead directly access the AppStorage values when/where you need them.

Regarding @MainActor, it’s not only for UI code but any code that can be accessed from UI code so if the singleton is only accessed from views then it’s a viable solution.

The one thing you don’t want to do is start labeling everything with MainActor. Read about Sendable and global actors. Singletons have their place but they are the exception.
